# Test impact of DSC script using vNext in Release Management

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, dsc

Following the examples on the web, it's not hard to set up a [working example for the first DSC script.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/07/22/deploying-using-powershell-desired-state-configuration-in-release-management.aspx)

However, I need to find a way to just list the changes that the script will make, not actually "make it so".

The challange that I have is that the script I want to test contains some Release Management specific variables that is populated during the release process. Like this:

```
# Copy website bits to configured deployment path
File CopyDeploymentBits
{
    Ensure = "Present"
    Type = "Directory"
    Recurse = $true
    SourcePath = $applicationPath
    DestinationPath = $($Node.DeploymentPath)
}
```

Is it possible to execute the script through the normal release path and just execute the "Test" part and get a log of what is OK/Not OK and not apply any changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't anything like that at this time.

Once the configuration is in place on a node, you could run `Test-DSCConfiguration` but by that point you've already applied config at least once.

Comment: Oh... Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there are any plans to implement such a feature? It would be quite useful.

Comment: Actually, yes. In DSC v5 (which you can preview in WMF 5 right now), there is a `Compare-DSCConfiguration` cmdlet which I believe does exactly what you are asking for. I haven't used it myself though.